# Rudin's proof of completion of product measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Setup:

$(1).\ $ For any pair $(X,\mathscr S), (X,\mathscr T)$ of measurable spaces, a measurable rectangle in $X\times Y$ is a set $A\times B$, with $A\in \mathscr S$ and $B\in \mathscr T.$

$(2).\ \mathscr S\times \mathscr T$ is defined to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $X\times Y$ that contains all measurable rectangles. (Not necessarily complete!)

$(3).\ $ If $Q$ is a measurable set in $(X\times Y,\mathscr S\times \mathscr T)$, the section $Q_x,$ is the set of all $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in Q.$ Similarly, the section $Q^y$ is $\{x\in X:(x,y)\in Q\}.$ Sections are measurable sets.

$(4).\ r,s,k$ are positive integers, $k=r+s.$

$(5).\ \ m_k$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^k,$ defined on  $\frak M$$_k,$ the smallest *complete* $\sigma$-algebra that contains the Borel sigma algebra $\frak B$$_k.$

$(6).\ $ The product measure $m_r\times m_s,$ on $(\mathbb R^r\times \mathbb R^s,\frak M$$_r \times \frak M$$_s)$ is defined to be $m_r\times m_s(Q)=\int_{\mathbb R^r}m_s(Q_x)dm_r,$ (which is indeed a measure and equal also to $\int_{\mathbb R^s}m_r(Q^y)dm_s).$

$(7).\ $ Fact: $\ \frak B$$_k=\frak B$$_r \times \frak B$$_s.$

The proof goes as follows:

$1).\ \frak B$$_k \subseteq \frak M$$_r \times \frak M$$_s\subseteq \frak M$$_k.$

$2).\ m_r\times m_s$ agrees with $m_k$ on $\frak M$$_r\times \frak M$$_s.$

From this, we conclude that $\frak M$$_k$ is the completion of $\frak M$$_r \times \frak M$$_s.$

But isn't it possible that the completion $\frak C$ of $\frak M$$_r \times \frak M$$_s$ is *properly* contained in  $\mathfrak M_k?$

I guess the answer is no because we would then have that $\frak B$$_k= \frak B$$_r \times \frak B$$_s\subseteq \frak C$, which contradicts $(5).$

The problem I have with this is that Rudin does not prove fact $(7)$ and as far as I can tell, it is not an exercise (unless I missed it somewhere). It's not hard to show, but the fact that it is not proved in the text leads me to believe that my reasoning in this proof may be faulty.

Comment: (1) should be "$\mathfrak M_k$ is the smallest *complete* $\sigma$-algebra ...". The smallest such $\sigma$-algebra is obviously $\mathfrak B_k$ itself.

Comment: `$\mathfrak M_k$` works, as does `${\frak M}_k$`. I would avoid `$\frak M$$_k$` as needlessly messy.

Comment: Also, you didn't say what you were proving before launching into the proof. One can only discern it when the conclusion is reached. And finally, how does Rudin define $\mathfrak B_r \times \mathfrak B_s$? The normal set-theoretic meaning is obviously not intended.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Please see my edit.

Comment: It is now (5) that is contradicted by $\mathfrak B_k \subseteq \mathfrak C \subset \mathfrak M_k$, not (7). And (7) is the statement that before the edit you said Rudin didn't prove or offer as an exercise. I see three possibilities: Either Rudin did include it somewhere you overlooked, or Rudin expected you to quickly spot how it could be proved and so didn't bother to explain, or else Rudin didn't realize that it wasn't included elsewhere. I can't judge the first, and from what I know of Rudin, I doubt the second. The third could easily be true, given how much rewriting goes into publishing.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Yes, I meant $(5).$ It's a typo. The only reason I asked the question, is I thought that I was missing some logical step in the proof. Because I could only do it using the fact $(7).$

Comment: No, your reasoning is not faulty. $\frak C$ must contain $\mathfrak B_r \times \mathfrak B_s = \mathfrak B_k$, and as it is complete, it must be that $\mathfrak M_k \subseteq \mathfrak C$. And since $\mathfrak M_r \times \mathfrak M_s \subseteq \mathfrak M_k$, its completion $\frak C$ must be a subset of $\mathfrak M_k$. Therefore $\mathfrak C = \mathfrak M_k$. I consider it most likely that at one time $\mathfrak B_r \times \mathfrak B_s = \mathfrak B_k$ was supposed to be an exercise or some earlier example, but in the process of rewrites it was dropped, forgetting its use here.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: OK, great. Thanks for the feedback.